# How to inject Admob Extension to a Codename One Project?

Tags: java, admob, codenameone

I'm having issues getting the Admob extension to work.
I initially just inserted the commands found on the extension's Github page (https://github.com/codenameone/admobfullscreen-codenameone) to the pml.xml file which did not work. So I then downloaded the Admob library in the extensions page in the CN1 settings program. When I do that, I get an error with common/pom.xml file - sometimes it says that the artifact can't be found. So, I then deleted the commands that were inserted in the common/pom.xml file from downloading it via the settings page. I then reinserted the commands said to insert from the Github page and then the admob extension works in the simulator.

I then built it my program locally in Android Studio to which it does not work because it cannot find the GoogleAPIs. I then just uploaded it to the cloud server and ran my game on an emulator (Genymotion) as I thought maybe it was just an error with Android Studio. My game ran in the emulator but whenever an ad was supposed to pop up, my game would simply freeze.

I think I am doing something wrong when I insert the library into my program and any guidance on how to properly insert Admob into my project would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to launch Codename One Settings from the maven target. Go to advanced -> Extensions and click "download". This automatically recognizes the type of extension and adds it to the pom correctly.

Comment: When I do, my game no longer can be built to server for android (get an error), I get errors when I build it locally in Android Studio when testing it out such as: Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START and the app does not build in XCode for iOS.

Comment: I can't help without actual error logs that you're getting. If they are too long you can create a git gist and provide a link. If they're private you can submit that to the chat in our website and link to this answer.

Comment: So I did get things to work perfectly for Android. I did get my program to run on iOS with admob injected on xcode, however, when I run my program on my phone with ads, when an ad is supposed to show, my program freezes and gives me this infinitely
2023-08-12 14:01:35.402624-0400 MyApp[48419:2669211] inside native getIsLoadedMainThread
2023-08-12 14:01:35.402695-0400 MyApp[48419:2669211] ad not loaded yet 
Is this something that will resolve if my app were to be published?

Comment: I doubt it. You should at least see a placeholder ad. This is a printout from the library, what other printouts do you see from here: https://github.com/codenameone/admobfullscreen-codenameone/blob/88bffee043f3705cf12c768cd594411dfa32af2c/ios/src/main/objectivec/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m#L33

Comment: I also get these printouts when the ad first "loads":::      
2023-08-13 13:35:31.364916-0400 MyApp[56220:2986498] inside native startLoadingAd
2023-08-13 13:35:31.365093-0400 MyApp[56220:2986498] inside native isLoaded - run on main thread
2023-08-13 13:35:31.365150-0400 MyApp[56220:2986135] start loading Ad :::    
Like I said, I then get the other printouts infinitely. I also observed in AdMob that my ad unit is getting impressions so I think it is "working" in a way but it just seems to crash my program.

Comment: So no `interstitialDidReceiveAd` or anything similar? That means an ad wasn't received from admob. I'm not sure why. If the app crashes can you add the stack from xcode and error to the question? Do you have access to that?

Comment: Thank you so much. This comment made me realize my Ad Unit ID and App ID were flip flopped.